# Buy a single product from bundle product

Tags: product, bundle, virtual

I have a set of Virtual products in a bundle product, Is there any way to make each of virtual products buy separately in Magento.

How to edit view of product list in a bundle?

I am new in Magento,I know only basics of Magento

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Which kind of products are that? Why did you choose a bundle? What do you mean with the editing the "view of product list in a bundle"?

Comment: @Alex,I need to buy virtual product in a bundle seperately

Answer (score 2):

Set the individual products to have visibility in "Catalog, Search" - I believe they currently have visibility set to "Not Visible Individually"

[image: Product admin screnshot]

Answer (score 1):

Might be better to use Grouped product as items can be ordered individual from a group.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the simple product's visibility to "Catalog, Search" if it is currently "Do not show individually". Then they would show up in the catalog and can be purchased separately.